# what is the difference between JFrame and FramView in Java?

Tags: java

1- what is the difference between JFrame and FramView in Java ??

2- when I create New Desktop Application with NetBeans , FrameView is created and when I put any component on it ( by design mode) it appears beautiful like this ( see picture 1 in bottom link )

but when Application run , it appears like this !!(see picture 2 in bottom link )

and when I create JFram and put a button on it , whenever Application run the button appears like this  ... !! (see picture 3 in bottom link )

why this happend ..?? I want to create a beautiful interface and component Like component on FramView but without any problem in design?
How I do that ??

Notice : I use NetBeans 6.8

see pictures http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/fc54702761.png

I am sorry because I put the Images in this way , but your web site prevent me from putting image and multi hyperlinks because I am a new user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves me right, the FrameView is a custom component by Netbeans. To make your JFrame components look "better", add the following code just before calling the `init()` method:

```
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form NewJFrame */
public NewJFrame() {
    try
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {    }

    initComponents();
}

.
. 
.
.
/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I put this code before calling the initComponents() method but it does't work ... 

this exception doesn't be thrown and the button stay ugly like previously .. :(

Comment: Hmm well, unless you put your code here we won't be of much help. I have edited my response to show the structure of my Java class as it is in netbeans. This works for me. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Humm last time I put this code In FramView , but Now I put it in JFram and it's work .

rightly thanks alot ... :) 

but I don't Know the different between JFram and FrameView yet .

Comment: Well, like I said earlier, the FrameView is a custom component developed by the people that developed Netbeans. I have tried using it a couple of times but I found it a bit complicated to use and have always reverted to the JFrame which never disappoints :)